# Creating VM's using kvm. Error: Unit libvirtd.service could not be found?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

**TLDR;**
On Ubuntu 20.04.1, I am trying to run VM's using KVM. After installing the required packages, I still get below error:

```
sudo systemctl status libvirtd
Unit libvirtd.service could not be found.
```

**The below is what I have done -**
a) check kvm support

```
$ sudo kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

b) install required packages

```
$ sudo apt install -y qemu qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon libvirt-clients bridge-utils virt-manager
```

Now, the above should be everything and I must be able to open the virt-manager gui and get going and the libvertd service should have been started already. But, there is no libvirtd service running on my machine still and there is no libvirtd.service unit installed.

And obviously, The virt-manager is not able to connect to the demon so the below errors -
After doing `$ sudo virt-manager` --> the virt-manager GUI starts with root permissions.
[image]
Clearly the window says -

> The libvirtd service does not appear to be installed. Install and run
> the libvirtd service to manage virtualization on this host.

And obviously, no VM creation is feasible and below is the error on attempting for same.
[image]

Reference - [How to Install KVM on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.tecmint.com/install-kvm-on-ubuntu/)
Note: This issue is not duplicate with - [KVM Virt-Manager Error: No active connection to Install on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932200/kvm-virt-manager-error-no-active-connection-to-installed-on)
(one answer here ask to install - libvirt-bin , but this packages does not exist in the repo.

```
$ apt list  libvirt-bin    
Listing... Done
```

Hardware: This attempt is on Quad-Core, Intel CPU Laptop.

**Edit - Following the comment from ajgringo619, i could solve the libvirtd.service issue. But other issues still persist.**
Below is also posted as seperate Q @ [Warning: KVM kernal modules are not loaded. Your VM may perform poorly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609243/warning-kvm-kernal-modules-are-not-loaded-your-vm-may-perform-poorly)
[image]
This is the lsmod output -

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_intel             282624  0
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_intel
```

Should I ignore the warning, is the performance really gonna be poor??

Comment: Did the `libvirt-daemon-system` package get installed?

Comment: no, it is not. I installed it and got past the `libvirtd.service` issue. But new issues are rising. Editing the Q with new issues.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to add your follow-up, which you’ve also asked as a separate question, would you mind posting the resolution as an answer?

Comment: Your "kvm not loaded" link is broken.

Comment: @ajgringo619, thx for pointing. Fixed the broken link.

Comment: What groups is your user a member of? Did you reboot after the install?

Comment: @ajgringo619, `adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare vboxusers libvirt` is there still anything to worry about.

Comment: @ajgringo619, yeah, I rebooted. and the issue of `KVM not available` is solved. But I don't get USB devices or Web Cam in the VM.

Comment: That should be asked as a new question; you'll get better and more focused responses.

Answer (score 13):

`sudo apt install libvirt-daemon-system` resolved the `libvirtd.service` issue as pointed by @ajgringo619